# How to group by and sum for every 7 days using linq lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a filtered list of results for particular month. I am working on report that should print this in excel. How to query so that I display the results in this format?
Expected format:

```
Date    Qty  Other fields
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Total

8
9
10
11
12
13
14
Total
...
29
30
31
Total
```

I need to group by using lambda expression. Note: not all days of the filtered month have returned results, but I need to display all days anyway.

Comment: What is the input to process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is you could do the integer division to `GroupBy` so that you will have value which is rounded to the nearest integer and then take the `Sum` per `Group` by `Select` statement:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => (x.Date - 1)/ 7)
    .Select(x => x.Sum(y => y.Qty));
```

Comment: @Nkosi ops, yes. Should be `-1`. Thanks! No, you didn't misinterpret any. You got my intention right.

Comment: In that case, you could use `x.Date.Day` (which represents the day of month of the month) instead of `x.Date`. Anyway, more details will help to answer the question more accurately. Also, if you have new questions (different from the original question), you should make a new post.